# performance issue on Spring Data Mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, performance, spring-data-mongodb

I've got an issue on spring data mongodb, in a method, I request a simple "find" which retrieve ~1000 Documents.

my spring data code is here:

```
Query myquery = query(where("ipp").is(ipp).and(CODE_MESURE).in(codes).and(DATE_MESURE).gte(iDateDebut).lt(iDateFin));
return template.find(myquery, MessageMongo.class);
```

And with JProfiler, I've got **~1,4sec** in the "find" method of MongoTemplate class.
Note: The request to MongoDB is not the problem, execution take less than 20ms.
[image]

But if try to request the same query with mongo java driver by traditional way:

```
final DBCollection collection = template.getCollection(Constantes.MONGO_COLLECTION_MESSAGES_PARAMETRES_VITAUX);
 final DBCursor cursor = collection.find(myquery.getQueryObject());
final List<MessageMongo> tab = new ArrayList<>();
 while (cursor.hasNext()) {
  final DBObject d = cursor.next();
  tab.add(new MessageMongo((String) d.get("origine"), (String) d.get("appareil"),
      (String) d.get("chambre"), (String) d.get("lit"), (String) d.get("uf"), (String) d.get("ipp"),
      (String) d.get("domaineIpp"), (String) d.get("iep"), (String) d.get("domaineIep"), (String) d.get("ej"),
      ((Date) d.get("dateReception")).toInstant(), (String) d.get("codeMesure"),
      (String) d.get("uniteMesure"), (Double) d.get("valeurMesure"), ((Date) d.get("dateMesure")).toInstant()));
 }
return tab;
```

My method execute in ~140ms (**10x faster** than mongoTemplate style !)
[image]
is there a bug in Spring Data Mongo, or I missed something to configure?
I prefer to write with, it is easier to read, but performance is so poor.

the Document class:

```
@Document(collection = Constantes.MONGO_COLLECTION_MESSAGES_PARAMETRES_VITAUX)
public class MessageMongo implements MessageModel {
  @Id
  private String id;
  private final String origine;
  private final String appareil;
  private final String chambre;
  private final String lit;
  private final String uf;
  @Indexed
  private final String ipp;
  private final String domaineIpp;
  private final String iep;
  private final String domaineIep;
  private final String ej;
  private final Instant dateReception;
  @Indexed
  private final String codeMesure;
  private final String uniteMesure;
  private final Double valeurMesure;
  @Indexed
  private final Instant dateMesure;
. . .
```

EDIT: **1,67sec** if I use MongoRepository with the named method:

```
public List<MessageMongo> findByIppAndCodeMesureInAndDateMesureBetween(final String ipp, final List<String> codesMesure, final Instant from, final Instant to);
```

[image]

EDIT2:
logs of spring data:

```
2017/12/04 15:44:59,455 INFO  [nio-8180-exec-4] fr.sib.sillage.biometrie.service.impl.MongoMessageService    : findByIppAndCodesBetweenDate ipp=102828799, codes=[147842], dateDebut=2017-12-02T13:46:59,dateFin=2017-12-03T01:46:59  
2017/12/04 15:44:59,482 DEBUG [nio-8180-exec-4] o.s.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryCreator          : Created query Query: { "ipp" : "102828799", "codeMesure" : { "$in" : [ "147842"]}, "dateMesure" : { "$gt" : { $java : 2017-12-02T12:46:59Z }, "$lt" : { $java : 2017-12-03T00:46:59Z } } }, Fields: null, Sort: null
2017/12/04 15:44:59,517 DEBUG [nio-8180-exec-4] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate          : find using query: { "ipp" : "102828799" , "codeMesure" : { "$in" : [ "147842"]} , "dateMesure" : { "$gt" : { "$date" : "2017-12-02T12:46:59.000Z"} , "$lt" : { "$date" : "2017-12-03T00:46:59.000Z"}}} fields: null for class: class fr.sib.sillage.biometrie.model.MessageMongo in collection: parametresVitaux
2017/12/04 15:44:59,517 DEBUG [nio-8180-exec-4] org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils           : Getting Mongo Database name=[LilleNoSQLDatabase]
2017/12/04 15:44:59,567 INFO  [nio-8180-exec-4] org.mongodb.driver.connection                                : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:6, serverValue:3003}] to hades:27017
2017/12/04 15:44:59,567 DEBUG [nio-8180-exec-4] org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command                          : Sending command {find : BsonString{value='parametresVitaux'}} to database LilleNoSQLDatabase on connection [connectionId{localValue:6, serverValue:3003}] to server hades:27017
2017/12/04 15:44:59,592 DEBUG [nio-8180-exec-4] org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command                          : Command execution completed
2017/12/04 15:44:59,796 DEBUG [nio-8180-exec-4] org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command                          : Sending command {getMore : BsonInt64{value=63695089133}} to database LilleNoSQLDatabase on connection [connectionId{localValue:5, serverValue:3004}] to server hades:27017
2017/12/04 15:44:59,862 DEBUG [nio-8180-exec-4] org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command                          : Command execution completed
2017/12/04 15:45:01,213 INFO  [nio-8180-exec-4] fr.sib.sillage.biometrie.service.impl.MongoMessageService    : findByIppAndCodesBetweenDate size=1281
```

EDIT 3:
I've expand the call Tree with org.springframework in full view in JProfiler, so I can view what's wrong with Spring Data MongoDB,
and here is the majority of time spent:
[image]
**2,5 sec total** with

- 1,290 calls of
  org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.readType (1,462
  ms)
- 1,290 calls of
  org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read
  (1,026 ms)

And what's the composition of two methods :
A majority of Class.forName (erk !) in the first readType
[image]

And it's less clear on the second call to MappingMongoConverter.read
[image]

I hope it will be easier to find the issue.

Comment: Did you try MongoRepository ?? Refer this [link](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/) and let me know.

Comment: Hi @SachithDickwella !
I've try it with the method like that

    _public List<MessageMongo> findByIppAndCodeMesureAndDateMesureBetweenOrderByDateMesureAsc(final String ipp, final String codeMesure,
                                                                                           final LocalDate dateDebut, final LocalDate dateFin);_


But it's worse, i've got **1,67sec**

Comment: Is it taking time same amount of time if try to call find twice, within a single execution context? Can you enable springframework mongodb logs and paste it here?

Comment: What is the resultant query in each case? Is it exactly same??

Comment: Maybe it's taking time in converting the result set to pojo back

Comment: @Timothy
I passed the same query object, named : "myquery" as you can see. I don't know what find method is doing, but there is a issue ihmo.
I'll try to activate it, but this is a very simple project !
My Document contains many attributes (15) but the traditionnal way is really fast and it doesn't seems to take time.

Comment: @SunandPadmanabhan it is taking same time, with twice or more calls. I've enable logs, but there are really few logs in spring data mongodb, i copy them in the original post here

Comment: @Jérémie, Try to add indexes on which you are using columns and try again!

Comment: @SachithDickwella as I said, it is not a query problem and indexes are already presents ;-)
The same query is passed in the two case, only the find method is really slow.

Comment: From the logs I can see that spring data is issuing 2 queries find and getMore, also from the logs timestamp, value these 2 commands are the one taking majority of time. Whereas using Mongodb driver you are fetching the cursor and directly iterating the results via cursor.

Comment: Thanks Sunand. Indeed there are two queries, but results return in less than 100ms
first find : 59,567 to 59,592
second getMore : 59,796 to 59,862
and then i've the majority time spended in ... nowhere :)
59,862 to 01,213 : so ... 1351 ms :-/
just in the spring data layers

Comment: How many time did you repeat the query? Are you aware of Java needing a few iterations till it runs fast? There's a lot of code in the framework which needs to be optimized. The first time call is very costly, after a few iterations, the overhead probably becomes negligible. And there's also classloading....

Comment: Hello @maaartinus ! Thanks for your answer, I 'm aware with Java warmup,  but with 100 calls, i've the same poor performance with spring data :-(

Comment: Can you please provide a sample project that's reproducing the difference? It looks like @johannes-rudolph's answer is the closest thing I can imagine as on 1.x we don't cache the failure to load a class described in the source document's `_class` property. I checked 2.0 and the caching for that is in place there. Did you try 2.0 already?

Comment: Hello ! 
Sorry, i've change office, so i can't access anymore to this project

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this applies to your exact case but I had a very similar situation with a lot of time being wasted in `ClassUtils.forName()` and `ClassLoader.load()`.

I've inspected the situation under the debugger and the root cause in my case was that the class I was trying to deserialize the document to had been moved to a different package. In this case, Spring Data can't properly cache type information and issues a slow and expensive `ClassLoader.load()` on the
persisted `_class` field **for each document**!

Of course, this class load is doomed to fail because it references a class that no longer exists at the location stored int the `_class` field of the document.

Comment: Good catch, Johannes. It looks like we're caching failures in 2.0 properly. I've filed [a ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1301) to fix that for 1.x as well.