# Mongotemplate performance issue

Tags: java, mongodb, performance, mongotemplate

First of all, I found similar question but nothing out there works for me, and its based on old version of MongoTemplate.
[performance issue on Spring Data Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47633812/performance-issue-on-spring-data-mongodb)

But, I'm facing the same issue. On dev environment I got around 700 Documents that looks more or less like this + a bit of extra String values in each one.

```
@Document
public class Document {
    @Id
    private String id;

    private List<SubDocumentA> subDocumentsA;
    private List<SubDocumentB> subDocumentsB;
}

public class SubDocumentA {
    private String type;
    private List<SomeData> someData;
}
```

The query I want to execute is, whats important here, executing this directly on mongo shell results in instant result. I'v also profiled database while using my application, query took around 5 ms.

```
Query query = new Query((Criteria.where("subDocumentA.type").is("someType")));
result = mongoTemplate.find(query, Document.class);
```

It returns a bit over 500 results on dev and probably 10-20 times more on production environment. The problem is, it takes 7-10 seconds on dev environment to (most likely) parse database response into POJO.

Here is what JProfiler shows
[image]
[image]

Comment: So do you have an index defined on the field you are using in the query? In all honesty showing profiler data ( and particularly screenshots of profiler data ) doesn't tell us anything new. At the very least this is a "network I/O operation" and it's kind of expected to be slower than parts of code which don't fetch data over the network. If your "query is slow", then that's something entirely different, and usually related to indexing. Tools like debuggers and profilers are a "last port of call" after you have narrowed down everything else. Not the first things you look at.

Comment: I dont have indexes now, planning to add them tho. The point is, query on database is fast. Running it inside mongo shell gives me result instantly. I ran profile on mongo too, queries called from my application were executed in less than 5 ms. Pictures I'v included shows everything from `mongoTemplate.find()` as root. Rest is my code that is executed really fast. Slice of db.system.profile `"nreturned" : 568, "responseLength" : 3017968, "millis" : 5`